# How do I hide the same content after opening with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a current element after it's been clicked. Right now if you click it, it will reopen, I don't want to nest the items, as I need these to be their own independent links. Here's my code:

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neo9a0xc/

```
<style>.targetDiv {display: none}</style>

<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>


<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to toggle the sliding up/down? If so, try leaving only this line in the function `jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();` (remove or comment out the first two)  - see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neo9a0xc/1/

Comment: You want to hide the a.showSingle element that was clicked, revealing any already hidden a.showSingle element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need both the `slideUp` and `hide` since when slideUp finishes it sets the display to none anyway. What you need to do is get the index of the element you click on, and then hide the targetDiv divs that aren't of the same index.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var idx = jQuery(this).index('.showSingle')
    jQuery('.targetDiv:not(:eq(' + idx + '))').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle(function() {
      if (jQuery('.targetDiv:visible').length == 0) jQuery('.showSingle').removeClass('selected');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
  display: none
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>


<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Comment: Can you also help me on how to put a class into the "showSingle" so I can apply a different color when the item is selected please?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that functionality

Comment: Thank you so much, however when toggling it leaves the class in the element.